# Can't send jQuery post data to MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've tried solutions from that I could find in Google, but nothing helped.
My ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: apiEndpoint + "/CreateExercise", 
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] === "{") {
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
            }
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateExercise(string sessionId, Exercise ExerciseCreateInfo)
```

Data that I want send:

```
data.sessionId =  sessionId;
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo = {};
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.IsVisible = true;
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.SimilarityNorm = $("#numSimilarityScore").val();
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.TypeId = $("#selectTaskType option:selected").val();
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.Name = $("#textTaskName").val();
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.Difficulty = $("#numDifficulty").val();
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.MarkPoints = $("#numPoints").val();
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.Question = tinyMCE.get("editorTask").getContent();
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.Hint = tinyMCE.get("editorHint").getContent();
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.Explanation = tinyMCE.get("editorExpenation").getContent();
    data.ExerciseCreateInfo.Fields = {};
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I can see my data in browser console, but on server side everything is null, except `sessionId`

Comment: Is ExerciseCreateInfo also the name of a type that you have? Can you post the involved objects (such as Exercise and any sub-objects)?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted Exercise class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, A person, who wrote MVC Controller used wrong namespace. Now everything is fine. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to controller with Several Ways :
in this sample you can send data to contoller with 3 way:

1. Ajax.BeginForm
2. Model
3. ViewModel
4. Ajax in Jquery
5. FormCollection
6. Definition Input
7. ...

[Download Sample.](http://up.ashiyane.org/images/vnb814kbp6g1jz4kfm2l.rar)