# Bind a button to an action in controller and pass model from view to controller in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use jQuery AJAX to bind a button to an action in my controller. I do it this way, but it's not working.

```html
@model InventoryTest.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "itemTypeForm" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" id="deleteButton"  class="button btn btn-danger" />

    <!-- other form elements... -->
}
```

In controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(MyModel myModel )
{
    if (myModel != null);
        // do something...

    return(view);
}
```

The AJAX code is:

```
$("#deleteButton").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (formIsValid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Delete',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize()
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert("sucsess")
            } else {
               alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Edit:

```
$("#deleteButton").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Delete',
            type: 'POST',
            **data:$("#itemTypeForm").serialize()**
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert("sucsess")
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    })
```

I changed AJAX part to access the form using its id,it now invoke the action but i get the error message and the returned model object is empty.

Comment: Where do `form` and `formIsValid` come from? Also the `if` condition in the action shouldn't have a `;` after it.

Comment: Can you specify what is not working? Is there any error coming?

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan :Actullay i am new in ajax,so i just where trying some code ,i think form is the form that contains the input button.

Comment: @ssilas777:   No there is no error but it also doesnt invoke the action in controller after i click delete button

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Where is the proper value for  dat?or how can i access the form that button is placed in?

Comment: See the following Link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967735/cant-send-jquery-post-data-to-mvc-controller/30968487#30968487

Comment: as soon as you press the delete button , it goes to default url that is currently in request, because your button is type submit. What is the sense in writing ajax code for it? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @raha if your are not sure about it give the form an id and use $('#id').serialize() or if there is only one form $('form').serialize()

Comment: instead of `Html.Beginform` you can use `Ajax.BeginForm` for ajax form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the current Id in hidden element where name must match.

Say your delete id name in Model is- `ProjectID`

**Then-**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "itemTypeForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ProjectID) //getting from above model
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" id="deleteButton"  class="button btn btn-danger" />

    <!-- other form elements... -->
}
```

**And then-**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(MyModel myModel )
{
    int projectID = myModel.ProjectID  //just to make sure if id is coming
    if (myModel != null);
        // do something...

    return(view);
}
```

This way you can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should  return Json, not a view.

And in your Ajax call, set the expected data type to Json aswell.

["basic ajax tutorial"](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html)